# React , filter based on two attribute from api not working..its taking only one value to filter

Tags: reactjs, search

how can i search by two names from api one is test_name and one is alt_name but i dont know why its taking only one value that is either test_name or alt_name if i replace their position ..i wamt to filter it based on test_name and alt_name all it taking is alt_name but if i give only test_name without giving && alt_name then it works..how can i solve this please anyone let me know

```
const searchFilter = text => {
if (text) {
  const newData = masterData.filter(item => {
    const itemData =
    (item.alt_name.toLowerCase()  && item.test_name.toLowerCase() && item.alt_name.toLowerCase()) 
        ? (item.alt_name.toLowerCase() && item.test_name.toLowerCase() && item.alt_name.toLowerCase())
        : '';
    const textData = text.toLowerCase();

    return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
  });
  setfilterdData(newData);
  setsearch(text);
} else {
  setfilterdData(masterData);
  setsearch(text);
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

text is your search value, filteredData is your result array:

```
const filteredData = text 
     ? masterData.filter(item =>
            item.test_name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase() || 
            item.alt_name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()
       ),
     ) : masterData;
```